# How to summarize data by clusters

Tags: r, data.table

Supposed I have the following data:

```
library(data.table)    
set.seed(200)
data <- data.table(income=runif(20, 1000,8000), gender=sample(0:1,20, T), asset=runif(20, 10000,80000),education=sample(1:4,20,T), cluster = sample(1:4, 20, T))
```

My data contain both continuous and categorical variables.  I want to summarize data based on the cluster variable as follows:

Continuous variables (income and asset): use `mean`, so I applied

`data[,lapply(.SD, mean), by = cluster, .SDcols = c(1,3)]`

Categorical variables (gender and education): I used

```
table(data[,gender, by = cluster])/rowSums(table(data[,gender, by = cluster]))

table(data[,education, by = cluster])/rowSums(table(data[,education, by = cluster]))
```

I do not think that my code is efficient.

Could you pleases give me suggestions how to deal with this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
data[, .N, by=.(gender, cluster)][, .(gender, ratio = N/sum(N)), by=cluster]
data[, .N, by=.(education, cluster)][, .(education, ratio = N/sum(N)), by=cluster]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `for` loop for the `categorical` variables

```
res <- list()
for(i in c('gender', 'education')){
   res[[i]] <- prop.table(table(cbind(data[,'cluster'], data[, ..i])), margin=1)
}

res
```

Or

```
lapply(data[,c('gender','education'), with=FALSE], function(x)
         prop.table(table(cbind(data[,'cluster', with=FALSE],x)), margin=1))
```